# In the "Pater Noster" prayer why is 'panem nostrum' sometimes "quotidianum" and other times "cotidianum"?

Tags: spelling

In the "Pater Noster" prayer, why is "panem nostrum cotidianum" sometimes written as "panem nostrum quotidianum"?

Answer (score 10):

*Quotidianum* and *cotidianum* are simply two different ways to spell the same word. This word belongs to a group of words that can be spelled with either a *QU* or a *C*, which includes *cum* and *quom*.

These interchangible spellings are probably due to a similar sound (in at least one dialect of Latin) between *QUO* and *CO* or *QUO* and *CU*. The same thing is happening a bit further down in the prayer with the spellings *caelis* and *coelis*, because the pronunciation of *AE* and *OE* sounds the same in some dialects.

Comment: Some spell it *cotidianum*, some spell it *quotidianum*, but the weirdest people are those who spell it *supersubstantialem* 

Comment: cum and quam are not "the same word".

Comment: @fdb: the answer says “quom”, not “quam”.

Comment: @fdb It's interesting that it was fashionable in certain pedagogical circles in the 19th and 20th centuries to distinguish between *cum* and *quom*, with *cum* being the preposition and *quom* being the conjunction. Woodcock says the distinction was not ancient.